# how to end typing in bot framework using Node js

Tags: node.js, botframework

How can I end the "typing" in bot framework (built using nodeJs).
The typing indicates even after the next message received from bot.

Comment: Hi akshay,

Could you please explain your question a little further?

What channel (Skype, WebChat, Facebook Messenger, etc.) are you using?

Are you using the `session.sendTyping()` function as [documented here?](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session#sendtyping)

A screenshot of the chat box could also be helpful in diagnosing your issue.

Thanks!

Comment: HI,
Actually am using it in Slack, "typing" notation still visible even after the new message arrives.
And yes am using "session.sendTyping()"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `context.sendActivity({ type:ActivityTypes.Typing})`

don't forget to import 'ActivityTypes' from 'botbuilder'